# How to create a view in SQL Server that pivots data from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, pivot

I have a table in SQL Server that has data I need but it's in a weird format that I cannot use. The data looks like this in the table:

```
Asset_ID     Process_ID     Datapoint_Name     Data_Value
27           62             Name               John
27           62             Location           United States
```

My goal is to create a view using the aforementioned table so the data is formatted like this:

```
Asset_ID     Process_ID     Name     Location
27           62             John     United States
```

I know how to create a view but I don't know how to achieve this in code. Can someone give me an example script on how to do this? Thanks.

To clarify for mods that previously closed my question: The values in the Name/Location columns above are strings, so using the SUM function isn't possible like in older posts asking similar questions. My question is somewhat unique because of this.

Comment: Search for case expression pivot

Comment: Within one asset-process group, is Datapoint Name guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @Reinderien yes

Comment: The linked answer is exactly what you need, just use `max` or `min` aggregation instead of sum (your question is not unique, this type of pivoting question is asked daily).